# How would you implement multiple items using NSOUtlineViews's pasteboardWriterForItem:

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I am using an NSOutlineView with drag and drop support. There is an NSOutlineViewDataSource function entitled outlineView(_:pasteboardWriterForItem:).

This call serializes the item passed into the function and allows the user to retrieve the serialized item in outlineView(_:acceptDrop:item:childIndex:)

```
@MainActor optional func outlineView(
    _ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
    acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
    item: Any?,
    childIndex index: Int
) -> Bool
```

That being said, I don't understand how I would write multiple rows of data using outlineView(_:pasteboardWriterForItem:) . It gets called for each item being moved, but the pasteboard only keeps a reference to the last item.  Apple deprecated several  multiple row write/move functions.

How should I implement this? I have tried several solutions but they're hacky and seem like they're not the canonical solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is in the `info` parameter.

There is an API [enumerateDraggingItems(options:for:classes:searchOptions:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdragginginfo/1416074-enumeratedraggingitems) of `NSDraggingInfo` to enumerate and proceed the items.

In `outlineView(_:pasteboardWriterForItem:)` you usually just

```
return item as? NSPasteboardWriting
```